# Big Integer class in visual studio

Tags: .net, numbers, biginteger

As you know, There is a class in Microsoft Visual Studio with Framework 4, 4.5, for working with big integers. What is the method name which used for multiplication in "BigInt" class ?

Comment: I think you're asking for the name of the _algorithm_.

Comment: @fejesjoco : Yes, I do.

Answer (score 1):

It is simply called [`Multiply`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.multiply(v=vs.110).aspx).

Example usage (from MSDN):

```
BigInteger number = BigInteger.Multiply(Int64.MaxValue, 3);
```

Comment: Dear sir, I know how to write a code. I asked what is the name of method for Multiplication ? ______ is it Montgomery method or what ?